# Published an asp.net Web Application in debug mode?

Tags: c#, asp.net, deployment

I have been publishing a web application project in debug mode.  I know there are a lot of questions on here regarding this, but I think they more pertain to window apps, but I could be wrong.  Basically, I was just curious on what the difference is and if it is a big difference in publishing an asp.net web application project built in debug mode as opposed to release mode?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Google](http://www.google.com/search?rlz=1C1GGLS_enUS305US306&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=ASP.Net+Debug+vs+Release+mode) brings up all sorts of stuff. It's probably best to start there, this has been [answered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28894/net-compiler-debug-vs-release) a [thousand times](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1114205/how-should-i-use-debug-release-mode-in-visual-studio).

Answer (score 2):

[Beware of deploying debug code in prodcution](http://aspnetresources.com/articles/debug_code_in_production.aspx)

[Debug and Release Builds in ASP.NET 2.0](http://odetocode.com/Blogs/scott/archive/2005/11/15/debug-and-release-builds-in-asp-net-2-0.aspx)

Try Googling and you will get lot of links.

Answer (score 2):

Having

```
<compilation debug="true">
```

Enabled in the web.config will a relatively large overhead, nevermind the security risks. Its always advised to disable this for production environments